# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence at fit(X, y) in k-nearest neighbor

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

i have an error at this line:neigh.fit(X, y) : 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I checked fit function and X is: {array-like, sparse matrix, BallTree, cKDTree}
My X is a list of list with first element solidity number and second elemnt humoment list (7 cells).
If i change and i take only first humoment number for having a pure list of list
give this error: query data dimension must match BallTree data dimension.

My code:

```
listafeaturevector = list()
path = 'imgknn/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):
    print("current file is: " + infile )
    gray = cv2.imread(infile,0)
    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) 
    graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
    imgbnbin = thresh

    #CONTOURS
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgbnbin, cv2.RETR_TREE ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print(len(contours))

    for i in range (0, len(contours)):
        fv = list()  #1 feature vector

        #HUMOMENTS
        #print("humoments")
        mom = cv2.moments(contours[i], 1)  
        Humoments = cv2.HuMoments(mom)
        #print(Humoments) 
        fv.append(Humoments) #query data dimension must match BallTree data dimension

        #SOLIDITY

        area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[i]) #ha tanti valori
        hull_area = cv2.contourArea(hull)
        solidity = float(area)/hull_area
        fv.append(solidity)

        #fv.append(elongation)
        listafeaturevector.append(fv)

print("i have done")
print(len(listafeaturevector))
lenmatrice=len(listafeaturevector)

#KNN
X = listafeaturevector
y = [0,1,2,3]* (lenmatrice/4)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X, y)  #ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))
print(neigh.predict_proba([[0.9]]))
```

If i try to covert it in a numpy array:

```
listafv = np.dstack(listafeaturevector)
listafv=np.rollaxis(listafv,-1)
print(listafv.shape)
data = listafv.reshape((lenmatrice, -1))
print(data.shape)

#KNN
```

X = data

i got: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: Please post a complete stacktrace instead of just the exception. It might contain useful information for solving your problem.

Comment: So the error is in converting to a numpy array, right? That is probably because the lists have different length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions/questions:

```
Humoments = cv2.HuMoments(mom)
```

What is the class of the return value `Humoments`? a `float` or a `list`? If `float`, that is fine.

```
for each image file
    for i in range (0, len(contours)):
       fv = list()  #1 feature vector
       ...
       fv.append(Humoments) 
       ...
       fv.append(solidity)
       listafeaturevector.append(fv)
```

The above code does not seem correct. In your problem, I think you need to a construct a feature vector for each image. So anything that is related to image `i` should go to the same feature vector `x_i`. Then you combine all feature vectors to get a list of feature vectors `X`. However, your `listafeaturevector` (or `X`) presents in the inner-most loop, it's obviously not correct.

Second, you have a loop against the number of elements in the `contours`, are you sure the number of elements stays the same for each image? Otherwise, the number of features (`|x_i|`) is totally different across different images, that might cause the error of

```
setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Third, are you clear about how you want to classify the images? what are the target values/labels of different images? I see you just setting labels with `[0,1,2,3]* (lenmatrice/4)`. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do with those images? Are they containing different type of object? Are they showing different patterns? Are those images describe different topic/color? If yes, for each different type, you give a different label -  either 0,1,2 or 'red','white','black' (assume you have only 3 types). The values of the label do not matter. What matters is how many values they have. I am trying to understand the difference of `labels` in your case.

On the other hand, if you only want to retrieve similar images, you don't need to use a classifier or specify a label for each image. Instead, try to use `NearestNeighbors`.

```
print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))
print(neigh.predict_proba([[0.9]]))
```

Fourth, the above two lines of test are not correct. You need to set an `X`-like object in order to get a prediction from the classifier. That is to say, you need a feature vector `x` with the identical structure as you constructed in your training examples (with all `h,e,s` in the same order).

Comment: Your answer was really precious! First of all: Humoment is a list, 2nd:every image has got many objects/contours and these number of objects/contours is not the same for every single image, last but not least i think i would try nearestNeighbors because i want only similar images! question: if a single image has only a single feature vector, my feature vector is a list of object/contour like this:  1st image: [ [h1,e1,s1], [h2,e2,s2] , [h3,e3,s3]] and X is a list of these feature vectors (that are matrices)?

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to flat your list and combine the elements so that for each image, it is a single list. Also make sure every feature vector contains the same number of elements and all elements present in the same order. e.g., 1st image: [`h1,h2,h3,e1,e2,e3,s1,s2,s3`], 2nd image `[h1',h2',h3', e1',e2',e3',s1',s2',s3'`]. You cannot have different number of objects/contours across images. Instead, you can use a max number of object, and use some default for those those does not have so many.

Comment: i change feature vector creation (now my feature vector is : 1st image: [h1,h2,h3,e1,e2,e3,s1,s2,s3]), i use max number of object and my y is [0,1,2,3]. New error: Found array with dim 4. Expected 31, this is the reason why i wrote [0,1,2,3]* (lenmatrice/4), 31 is the number of my images/feature vectors

Comment: You don't need a y at all. Please see example of NearestNeighbor.fit(X). Since you don't need a classifier.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, i use nearestNeighbor function: print(neigh.kneighbors(fv)) where fv is the feature vector of an image and this is result: (array([[ 2.28996567,  2.38927531,  2.46947026]]), array([[1, 5, 3]])). how can i know which image these result represent? Must i create a little dictionary featurevector-->image?

Comment: @postgres, first congrats for your progress! Next you might want to read http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html; especially the signature of `kneighbors`. The return values are :  `dist : array`, Array representing the lengths to point, `ind` : array, Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix. So that you know `[1, 5, 3]` are the closest images, where `1,5,3` are their indices in your original `X`. Hope it helps.